# Exterior derivative calculation in Chern and Hamilton paper

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, exterior-derivative

Chern and Hamilton in their paper "*On Riemannian metrics adapted to three-dimensional contact manifolds*" constructed an structure on 3-sphere as follows (Example 3.2 of paper):

> Let 
>   $$\omega_1=xdy-ydx+zdw-wdz,\quad \omega_2=xdz-zdx+ydw-wdy,\quad \omega_3=xdw-wdx+ydz-zdy, $$
>   Taking exterior derivative we have:
>   $$d\omega_1=2\omega_2\wedge \omega_3,\quad d\omega_2=2\omega_3\wedge \omega_1,\quad d\omega_3=2\omega_1\wedge \omega_2.$$

But my calculations show that:
$$d\omega_1=2(dx\wedge dy+dz\wedge dw)\neq 2\omega_2\wedge \omega_3=2(z^2-w^2)dx\wedge dy+2(x^2-y^2)dz\wedge dw+2(xw-yz)(dx\wedge dz-dy\wedge dw)+2(xz-yw)(dy\wedge dz-dx\wedge dw),$$

Which part of my calculation is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this on the sphere
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1?$$
If so then
$$x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz+w\,dw=0$$
there.
Try using these relations in addition to your calculations.

Comment: I tried to simplify my calculation using your zero 1-form, but not helpful.

Comment: @C.F.G Did you also use $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$? If you really cannot derive these equations from these relations, then they aren't true.

Comment: It seems that I must try again because this paper is written by two great geometers.